# Where to reach potential buyers/users for your software - something like an AppStore for Windows

Tags: windows

I am Mobile-developer and 3 major mobile-platforms have channels for their users to get/buy software and for their developers to distribute/sell their creations, namely AppStore (IPhone), Marketplace (Windows Mobile) and Android Market (Android).

I have now written a software running on Windows. I have "spread the word" by publishing some articles on various forums/blogs but still it's difficult "to reach out". Are you aware about any similar "store", like AppStore, for Windows Users? I am not but I might be wrong. Or are you aware about any huge forum/blog where developers can advertise their applications?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no centralized store for arbitrary applications. If your product is consumer targeted, Download.com is a major shareware destination. If your product is niche, I suggest seeking out communities around your market and advertise on the respective forums, or simply run Google AdWords.